# Controlling div position in html using if statement from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I have an array in javascript. HTML prints the elements of the array in a div on the screen. But I would like the position of the div to change depending on the amount of elements in the array. And I use CSS margins and padding to control the position of the div on the screen. So how is it possible to do this. There must be some way but I just can't think of any. Maybe I need to use something else, separate form javascript altogether.

If CSS and javascript wee together it would look something like this:

```
div{

    margin: 100*array.length px;

}
```

or

```
if(array.length > 3){

     margin:400px;

   }else{

     margin:200px;

   }
```

If there is an easier way, instead of using margin and padding, let me know. And if I have to start fro scratch with my code, let me know.
I know it won't be near this simple. But what is the simplest way to do this. And what should I study to be able to do this. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it...

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.margin = 100 * array.length + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS class based on the array length - for example,if you put that value in an array myArrayLength, then you could do this with jQuery.

```
if (myArrayLength > 3) {
   $('div').addClass('wider');
}
```

in the CSS

```
div {
   width:300px;
}
div.wider {
   width:600px;
}
```